# Como personalizar a track de um slider de acordo com o valor dele

Tags: javascript, css3

O input do tipo range, por padrão no chrome, vem com o seguinte "efeito":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como reproduzi-lo, eu retirei todos os estilos padrões desse input, consegui personalizar tudo, mas não consegui reproduzir esse efeito.

Atualmente ele esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```css
.slider
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: ridge;
    background: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
}



.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb 
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(188, 216, 255); /*Cor para substituição da imagem original */
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="70" class="slider" id="Volume">
```

Creio que deve ser necessário o uso de JS, mas tudo bem, só quero uma solução.

Comment: Poderia postar o código CSS e HTML do que você conseguiu fazer até o momento?

Comment: Claro! Ja edito a pergunta. Não achei que seria necessário.

Comment: Pronto!! Coloquei os codigos.

Comment: Cara no final das contas não deu para entender bom o que vc quer fazer... pelo meno eu não entendi o que seria esse "efeito" que vc diz

Comment: @hugocsl pelo que entendi, é cor de fundo azul do espaco percorrido pelo seletor do input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, podemos usar somente o JavaScript e trabalhar o `background` sem alterar o arquivo CSS. Podemos estilizar e alterar a cor apenas alterando uma variável no código JavaScript.

Podemos ajustar a propriedade do `background` do `input` via JavaScript usando `style.setProperty('background', ...);`. O segundo parâmetro que iremos passar será uma template-string com o seguinte formato:

```js
`linear-gradient(to right,  
                ${color} 0%,  
                ${color} ${value}%,
                #fff ${value}%, 
                #fff 100%)`
```

- `color` será uma cor que iremos usar para o `background`, pelo seu código creio que seja `rgb(188, 216, 255)`;
- `value` será o valor do seletor

Basicamente o que estamos dizendo é que a cor antes do seletor será uma (`rgb(188, 216, 255)`), depois do seletor será branca (`#fff`) e o seletor será a interseção dessas duas cores. Usamos o `linear-gradient` para seguirmos o paradigma POG (*Programação Orientada a Gambiarra*).

Vamos ao código JavaScript:

- Criei uma variável que será a nossa cor escolhida.
- Selecionamos o elemento do input.
- Acessamos o valor atual do input, já que pelo seu código ele começa com valor `70`. Isso é importante pra já adicionarmos a cor do "campo" percorrido pelo seletor

```js
const usedColor = 'rgb(188, 216, 255)';
const range = document.getElementById('Volume');
const currentValue =
  ((range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min)) * range.max;
```

`updateBackgroundColor` é uma função que vou chamar para atualizar a cor do `background` percorrido pelo seletor, passando o valor atualizado do seletor e a cor de preenchimento. Vamos chamar a função imediatamente para já preencher a cor do que já foi percorrido pelo seletor por causa do `value="70"`:

```js
const updateBackgroundColor = (value, color) => {
  range.style.setProperty(
    'background',
    `linear-gradient(to right,  ${color} 0%,  ${color} 
      ${value}%,
      #fff ${value}%, 
      #fff 100%)`,
  );
};

updateBackgroundColor(currentValue, usedColor);
```

Agora adicionamos um *listener* para o input atulizar o `background` a cada alteração de valor do input:

```js
range.addEventListener('input', function () {
  // retorna o valor atual do seletor
  const updatedValue =
    ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * this.max;

  // chama a função que atualiza o background
  updateBackgroundColor(updatedValue, usedColor);
});
```

Veja código JavaScript completo:

```js
const usedColor = 'rgb(188, 216, 255)';
const range = document.getElementById('Volume');
const currentValue =
  ((range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min)) * range.max;

const updateBackgroundColor = (value, color) => {
  range.style.setProperty(
    'background',
    `linear-gradient(to right,  ${color} 0%,  ${color} 
     ${value}%,
     #fff ${value}%, 
     #fff 100%)`,
  );
};

updateBackgroundColor(currentValue, usedColor);

range.addEventListener('input', function () {
  // retorna o valor atual do seletor
  const updatedValue =
    ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * this.max;

  // chama a função que atualiza o background
  updateBackgroundColor(updatedValue, usedColor);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: ridge;
  background: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(
    188,
    216,
    255
  ); /*Cor para substituição da imagem original */
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="range"
      min="1"
      max="100"
      value="70"
      class="slider"
      id="Volume"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Usando uma outra cor para o `background` alterando somente o `usedColor`:

```js
const usedColor = 'rgb(50, 0, 0)';
const range = document.getElementById('Volume');
const currentValue =
  ((range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min)) * range.max;

const updateBackgroundColor = (value, color) => {
  range.style.setProperty(
    'background',
    `linear-gradient(to right,  ${color} 0%,  ${color} 
     ${value}%,
     #fff ${value}%, 
     #fff 100%)`,
  );
};

updateBackgroundColor(currentValue, usedColor);

range.addEventListener('input', function () {
  // retorna o valor atual do seletor
  const updatedValue =
    ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * this.max;

  // chama a função que atualiza o background
  updateBackgroundColor(updatedValue, usedColor);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: ridge;
  background: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(
    188,
    216,
    255
  ); /*Cor para substituição da imagem original */
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="range"
      min="1"
      max="100"
      value="70"
      class="slider"
      id="Volume"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>Não sei se existe uma maneira de se fazer usando somente CSS :|</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado, creio que não exista mesmo não, mas não tem problema, realmente só queria uma resposta, não estava achando em lugar nenhum. Muito obrigado ^-^